# Access to the current changeset from CustomChange implementations

Tags: liquibase

I have an implementation of `CustomChange` that I need access to the file name of the changeSet in which it is defined.

Any ideas?  The `CustomChangeWrapper` has a reference to the `ChangeSet` that does have the value I need (*changeSet.filePath*) but is not passed as part of the `CustomChange` interface.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the source, I would try using the `public SortedSet<String> getParams()` and/or the `public String getParamValue(String key)` methods that are defined in `CustomChangeWrapper`

Comment: But how do you get a hold of `CustomChangeWrapper`?

Comment: I assumed your CustomChange implementation extended CustomChangeWrapper. If that is not the case, perhaps you could share the source for your custom change.

Comment: I would guess `CustomChangeWrapper` is not meant to extended, nor would any of the attributes be set when you do extend it?